# dnsdomainname and hostname -f does not return FQDN

Tags: dns, hostname

I have one box (Rasberry Pi, running rasberian) with a static IP. It's running in a network with a domainname, and I have several DNS-server set up.

However, I can not get FQDN name to work on this box:

```
sitron@pi:~ $ domainname
(none)
sitron@pi:~ $ dnsdomainname 
sitron@pi:~ $ hostname -f
pi
```

I believe I have set up DNS correctly:

```
sitron@pi:~ $ hostname -I
192.168.10.9 2001:db8:abba::9 

sitron@pi:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
domain example.org
search example.org
nameserver 2001:db8:abba::5
nameserver 192.168.10.5

sitron@pi:~ $ dig +short -x 192.168.10.9 @2001:db8:abba::5
pi.example.org.

sitron@pi:~ $ dig +short -x 2001:db8:abba::9 @2001:db8:abba::5
pi.example.org.

sitron@pi:~ $ dig +short -x 2001:db8:abba::9 @192.168.10.5
pi.example.org.

sitron@pi:~ $ dig +short -x 192.168.10.9 @192.168.10.5
pi.example.org.
```

My nsswitch.conf:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

And /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   pi
```

What is the missing link?

Comment: try to add `options single-request-reopen` into your  `/etc/resolve.conf` file. this should fix any mistake happens when you are using both ipv4 and ipv6 into your `resove.conf` "The resolver uses the same socket for the A and AAAA requests.  Some hardware mistakenly sends back only one reply.  When that happens the client system will sit and wait for the second reply.  Turning this option on changes this behavior so that if two requests from the same port are not handled correctly it will close the socket and open a new one before sending the second request."

Comment: Can you try changing the first line in `/etc/hosts` like this: `127.0.0.1 pi.example.com pi localhost`?

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna: I tried, but it did not work :-/

Comment: @FedonKadifeli: That will work, but that will break the hostname "localhost" pointing at 127.0.0.1, which both I and the system relay on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and there is two solutions. I have tested both, on several different boxes.

## Solution A

Verify that your `resolv.conf` contains the "domain"-keyword, like this:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
domain example.org
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

If you are using `dhcpcd.conf` to set a static IP like me, you have to specify this undocumented option:

```
static domain_name=example.org
```

Finally, you need to **remove** the line in `/etc/hosts` containing `127.0.1.1 <hostname>`. That means my `/etc/hosts` now contains:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

## Solution B

Add your FQDN to the 127.0.1.1 line in `/etc/hosts`, like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   pi.example.org pi
```

However, this means I am overriding the DNS-server, something that is not ideal. That's why I prefer, and assume *Solution A* is better.